# Azure App Service: application settings vs environnement vars (php-fpm)

Tags: php, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying my php app with a custom docker container in Azure App Service, my container is using Apache - PHP-FPM, my question is how to access these variables from php environment after deployment ?

at the moment I'm testing with the following php file:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
```

But I can't see variables i set.

Any advise ? thanks

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SERVER)`.

Comment: @Tajni same result, my vars are not shown.

Comment: Try `print_r(getenv("DB_HOST"))`. For more details, pls check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#access-environment-variables .